# How to save chatter post image as attachment

Tags: attachment, feeditem, images

Whenever an image is posted in record chatter feed post, i want to save that image into attachment. How can i get the image from record feedpost.

```
trigger FeedToattach on FeedItem (after insert) {
    system.debug('^^^'+trigger.new[0].Id);
    List<Attachment> lstToAttach = new List<Attachment>();
    ContentDocumentFeed objDoc = [Select Id,ParentId from  ContentDocumentFeed order by createdDate Desc limit 1];
    system.debug(objDoc.ParentId);
    for(FeedItem objFI : Trigger.New){ 
        Attachment objAttach = new Attachment(); 
        objAttach.Body = objFI.ContentData; }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The file is available in Content Version object in salesforce.

You can trigger on the feed post. Write an after insert trigger on feed post to copy the file to attachment

Comment: I have tried the trigger but don't know how to get the attached image. Am getting the error as "Invalid field ContentData for SObject FeedItem". for(FeedItem objFI : Trigger.New){
         Attachment objAttach = new Attachment();
         objAttach.Body =   objFI.ContentData; 
    }

Comment: Can you post the code so we look what have you tried?

Comment: Please find the code in the post

Comment: @Shashi Your trigger shouldb be on content document and not feed item

Comment: which field i can use to get the Body from the image to add in attachment.